# mac版Unityに於けるOPENCVについてうまくできない。

Tags: unity3d, opencv

こんにちは、いつもお世話になってます。

今、私はmac版UnityにOPENCVを入れようとしています。そこでこのサイトを見ながらやったのですが、↓

[UnityでOpenCVを動かしてみよう（主にMac対応）](http://warapuri.tumblr.com/post/70283352060/unity%E3%81%A7opencv%E3%82%92%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E4%B8%BB%E3%81%ABmac%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C)

libcxcore.dylibがないというエラーでうまく動作させれませんでした。libcxcore.dylibについていろいろサイトにあることを参考にやったのですがうまくできませんでした。

ぜひご教示お願いします。